# CiviCRM WordPress uninstall - db issue

Tags: wordpress, database, installation, settings

Uninstall CiviCRM from WordPress, is creating me a big issue.

I needed to uninstall CiviCRM (5.31.1) from a production site, saving all theme and others settings.
CiviCRM went away without uninstall its db data. So:

1. I tried to delete the tables using phpmyadmin, failing
2. From command line, I dropped the db and I recreated it from a dump, cutting away the CiviCRM part, maining all tables without `wp_` prefix; doing this the Wordpress site operate all as well.

Some days ago it was necessay to reinstall CiviCRM... All was good until we clicked the plugin enable link, recieving this page:

```
Initialization Error

Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => simpleHandler
        )

    [code] => -18
    [message] => DB Error: no such table
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'sat_wp2020.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'sat_wp2020.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such table" code=-18 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix="" info="SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'sat_wp2020.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]"]
```

Where old CiviCRM data are still inside db?

Did someone prepare a SQL script performing correct db uninstall?

Could be possibile to add the data delete checkbox during plugin uninstall process, like in many others Wordpress plugins?

TIA -- Francesco

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you still have a civicrm.settings.php file. To uninstall you need to delete that too.

Comment: Before to say a YES I controlled some old backup too. It's correct, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the 'civicrm' folder in 'wp-content/uploads' to be able to reinstall the plugin